# Why my computer is not accessible over internet?

Tags: remote-desktop, ping

I connect my computer to internet through my airtel mobile (3G).  This computer has no firewalls ON at all, neither OS's (XP) firewall nor any Anti-Virus's Firewall. 
ICMP also enabled.

Why can't i ping this machine from some other machine ??
Why this machine is completely hidden over internet from PING / REMOTE DESKTOP or some other remotely connecting application ???

I can ping other machines but not this one 117.96.0.63

Comment: Can you ping other machines?

Comment: What's your IP address? I wonder if your carrier is using a 'local' ip address range

Comment: yes i can ping other machines but this one 117.96.0.63

Comment: Maybe the host just doesn't answer pings.  Some don't.

Comment: Means this computer can't be used as HOST on internet forever ?

Comment: ask about this "Bharti Tele-Ventures Limited" or "Bharti Airtel Ltd"